# Bottle seem stuck because of response generation

Tags: python, subprocess, bottle

I am trying to connect to a backend (other python script) where a response is getting generated. This takes a little and seems like its crashing the response of bottle. Please have a look here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-s

from bottle import route, run, response, request
import subprocess

sherlockQueryScriptPath = ".\sherlock-backend\Sherlock_Queries.py"
emptyJsonString = "{}"

def main():
    #print prepareJson("test")
    #sys.exit(0)
    run(host='localhost', port=8080, threaded=True)

def prepareJson(query):
    queryProcess = subprocess.Popen(
        [sherlockQueryScriptPath, '-j', '-q', query],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True
    )
    queryProcess.wait()                # <== seems to cause problems
    result, error = queryProcess.communicate()

    if error:
        print "Error: ", error
        return emptyJsonString

    return result.strip()

def cors(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        response.content_type = 'application/json; charset=UTF8'
        response.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        response.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
        response.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type")

        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@route('/sherlockQuery.json')
@cors
def respondToGet():
    query = request.query.q
    return prepareJson(query)

@route('/sherlockQuery.json', method='POST')
@cors
def respondToPost():
    query = request.forms.get('q')
    return prepareJson(query)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Could someone tell my how to make its work? Or hold the connection till response is ready and then send it?

Comment: assuming you're using Python3, and if not, why not? Anyway, you don't want `Popen`, you want `.check_output`, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: well this is a little bigger project and i am stuck with 2.7 (would prefer py3 as well). is there any 2.7 solution?

Comment: check_output is still (was already?) available on 2.7